# How are side effects and observable behavior related in C++?

Tags: c++, side-effects

C++03 Standard 1.9/6 defines *observable behavior*:

> The observable behavior of the abstract machine is its sequence of reads and writes to volatile data and calls to library I/O functions.

and then and then 1.9/7 defines *side effects*:

> Accessing an object designated by a volatile lvalue (3.10), modifying an object, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

Is a side effect an observable behavior or not? How are they related to each other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, a side effect is not necessarily observable behaviour. Modifying a non-volatile object, for example, is a side effect, but not observable. The difference matters because the side effects may be rearranged or removed altogether by the compiler, so long as the observable behaviour remains the same.

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a = 30;
    a += 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Most compilers will, if requested, remove `a` completely. That's permitted. The assignments and addition aren't observable.

All observable behaviour must necessarily be a side effect though.